# mypy: Missing type parameters for generic type "Connection" [type-arg] when type hinting pymysql.connections.Connection

Tags: python, mypy, pymysql

mypy is saying "Missing type parameters for generic type "Connection"  [type-arg]" when I type hint these pymysql Connection types:

```
import typing
from dataclasses import dataclass

import pymysql
from loguru import logger


@dataclass
class ConnectionDetails:
    """Database connection details container class."""

    host: str
    port: int
    database: str
    username: str
    password: str


def connect(connection_details: ConnectionDetails) -> pymysql.connections.Connection:
    """Attempt to connect to a database."""

    try:
        return pymysql.connect(
            host=connection_details.host,
            port=connection_details.port,
            database=connection_details.database,
            user=connection_details.username,
            password=connection_details.password,
            cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor,
        )
    except pymysql.OperationalError as exc:
        logger.error(f"Connection failed: {str(exc.args[1])}")
        raise


def select(sql: str, connection: pymysql.connections.Connection) -> list[dict[str, typing.Any]] | None:
    """Select data from the database connection."""

    with connection:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            try:
                # Execute the query
                cursor.execute(sql)
            except pymysql.err.OperationalError as exc:
                logger.error(f"SQL error: {str(exc.args[1])}")
                return None

            try:
                # Fetch the result
                result = cursor.fetchall()

                if result:
                    return list(result)

                return None

            except pymysql.err.ProgrammingError as exc:
                logger.error(f"SQL error: {str(exc.args[1])}")
                return None
```

Inspection of the return type of the `connect` function suggests `Connection[Cursor]`, but I can't subscript `Connection`. I haven't been able to find much help in the [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/tree/main/stubs/PyMySQL/pymysql) either.

Does anyone know how I might make mypy happy here?

Comment: "can't subscript Connection"?  Are you using an old version of Python that doesn't understand generic types?  If so a workaround might be to specify the annotation as a string, i.e. `'Connection[Cursor]'`.